# android ApplicationInfo.sharedLibraryFiles return null

Tags: android

I have installed an app on emulator, pkg name="com.example.plug". In data/data/com.example.plug/lib, there is a "libplugin1.so" file.

Now I want to get it in my own app.

I get the packageName, and then the "nativeLibraryDir", but when I try to get the `String[] sharedLibraryFiles`, it returns null to me.

My codes are below:

```
Log.d(TAG, "pkgName=" + pkgName);// fine com.example.plug

ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(pkgName, PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES);

Log.d(TAG, appInfo.nativeLibraryDir);       // API 9 /data/data/com.example.plug/lib

String[] soList = appInfo.sharedLibraryFiles;   //null
```

Comment: Same problem here but on Mono Droid: ApplicationInfo.SharedLibraryFiles throws NullPointerException (HTC Desire with 2.2)

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I got the same issue, have you guys found solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It helps for me:

```
packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES)
```